# I need to parse an XML file using python, but I cannot import any library that requires pip

Tags: python, xml, list, parsing

The situation is I need the book title & number value under Score and place them on a 2d list. My current code, can retrieve the book title and score place them on a list, but the problem is there's some sections in the XML file where the score is not present, and I need to be able to leave an indicator (ex. N/A) on the list to indicate that value is empty for that particular book title.

Please Note:
[Asked this question previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74478984/parsing-an-xml-document-using-python-cannot-use-any-library-that-requires-pip), but the answer included a library function using pip, and was too narrow in scope. It included an answer that assumed the problem only appears once in the xml file, as it does here in the sample xml file.

This is a sample, simplified version of the xml file. There are in 100+ book titles and scores in the full xml file. Some contain scores, some do not. Thus no code can use, [1] as an index to get past this problem. This question is being posted again to avoid that very problem.

```
<bookstore>
            <book>[A-23] Everyday Italian</book>
               <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
                   <year>2005</year>
                  <price>30.00</price>
               <field></field>
          <key id="6408">[A-23]Everyday Italian</key>
               <brief>Everyday Italian</brief>
                <success></success>
                        <province> id="256" key=".com.place.fieldtypes:float">
                    <name>Post</name>
                    <numbers>
                           <number></number>
                </numbers>
                 </province>
                        <province> id="490" key=".com.ave.fieldtypes:float">
                    <name>Score</name>
                    <numbers>
                           <number>4.0</number>
                </numbers>
                 </province>
                        <province> id="531" key=".com.spot.fieldtypes:float">
                    <name>Doc</name>
                    <numbers>
                           <number></number>
                </numbers>
                 </province>
   </bookstore>
<bookstore>
            <book>[A-42] Pottery</book>
               <author>Leo Di Plos</author>
                   <year>2012</year>
                  <price>25.00</price>
               <field></field>
          <key id="4502">[A-42] Pottery</key>
               <brief>Pottery</brief>
                <success></success>
                        <province> id="627" key=".com.tri.fieldtypes:float">
                    <name>Post</name>
                    <numbers>
                           <number></number>
                </numbers>
                 </province>
                        <province> id="124" key=".com.doct.fieldtypes:float">
                    <name>Doc</name>
                    <numbers>
                           <number></number>
                </numbers>
                 </province>
   </bookstore>
<bookstore>
            <book>[A-12] Skipping the Line</book>
               <author>Gloria Gasol</author>
                   <year>1999</year>
                  <price>22.00</price>
               <field></field>
          <key id="1468">[A-23]Skipping the Line</key>
               <brief>Skipping the Line</brief>
                <success></success>
                        <province> id="754" key=".com.cit.fieldtypes:float">
                    <name>Post</name>
                    <numbers>
                           <number></number>
                </numbers>
                 </province>
                        <province> id="211" key=".com.soct.fieldtypes:float">
                    <name>Score</name>
                    <numbers>
                           <number>12.0</number>
                </numbers>
                 </province>
                        <province> id="458" key=".com.lot.fieldtypes:float">
                    <name>Doc</name>
                    <numbers>
                           <number></number>
                </numbers>
                 </province>
   </bookstore>


........................
and so on
100+ more times
```

The is the code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import re

tree = ET.parse('book.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

book = []
for book in root.iter('book'):
    item1 = book.text
    book.append(item1)

score = []
for province in root.iter('province'):
    for child in province:
        for grandchild in child:
            if re.match('^[+-]?\d*?\.\d+$', grandchild.text) != None:
                item2 = float(grandchild.text)
                score.append(item2)

print(book, score)
```

The expected output is:

```
([A-23] Everyday Italian, 4.0), ([A-42] Pottery, N/A), ([A-12] Skipping the Line, 12.0), .....
etc up to 100+ items on this list
```

Actual output is:

```
([A-23] Everyday Italian, 4.0), ([A-42] Pottery, 12.0), ([A-12] Skipping the Line)
```

Comment: The code iterates over a tag "title" which isn't anywhere in the sample data.

Comment: corrected for that previous error

Comment: Use only a single outmost for-loop which iterates over the "bookstore" tags. In the loop search for "book" and "province" tags based on the "bookstore" element instead of document root. From the found information create a tuple with title and score (if found or "N/A" if not found).

Comment: Please don't repeat a question just because you didn't like any of the answers you got. You should write a new question if it is actually different. If you wish to clarify or emphasise features of the question, you should edit it (which will also bump it up on attention lists).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("your_xml_file.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

out = []
for bookstore in root.iter("bookstore"):
    name = bookstore.find("book").text
    score = bookstore.find('.//*[name="Score"]')
    if score:
        score = score.find(".//number").text
    out.append((name, score or "N/A"))

print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
[
    ("[A-23] Everyday Italian", "4.0"),
    ("[A-42] Pottery", "N/A"),
    ("[A-12] Skipping the Line", "12.0"),
]
```